# tab delimited to csv

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I am able to get this to output my MYSQL command which I have removed for security, however I          keep getting an error when I try and write this tab delimited output to a CSV.  Any help to boost the      Python rookie would be appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/pytho
import sys, csv
import MySQLdb
import os
import mysql.connector
import subprocess
import string
 if __name__ == '__main__':

du = sys.argv[1]
csv_home = '/home/oatey/bundle_' + du + '.csv'
input = sys.stdin
output = sys.stdout


#read and rewrite to file with arguement
new = open("/home/oatey/valid.sql2", "w")    
with open("/home/oatey/bundle.sql")as write_query:
#read_file = write_query.read()

     for line in write_query:
     lr = line.replace('{$$}', du)
     print lr
     new.write(lr)
     new.close()
     write_query.close()         
with open("/home/oatey/valid.sql2") as w:
     mysql_output = subprocess.check_output(MYSQL_COMMAND, stdin=w)    

     #print mysql_output
     b = open("/home/oatey/" + du + ".txt", "r+")
    #",".join("%s" % i for i in mysql_output
     b.write(mysql_output)
     print mysql_output        
b.close()

#read tab-delimited file
with open("/home/oatey/" + du + ".txt", 'rb') as data:    
     cr = data.readlines()
     contents = [line for line in cr]

with open("/home/oatey/" + du + ".csv", "wb") as wd:
     cw = csv.writer(wd, quotechar='', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
     wd.write(contents)
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: while you are executing your command through subprocess, could asking mysqldump to do the job for you and export to CSV be an option?

`mysqldump -u [username] -p -t -T/path [database] --fields-enclosed-by=\" --fields-terminated-by=,`

Comment: normally yes....but this is part of an automated step where the user enters the path of the csv...

Answer (score 1):

I bet the error you are getting is:

> TypeError: must be string or buffer, not list

`contents` is a list, you cannot write a list via `write()`. Quote from [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.write):

> file.write(str)
>
> Write a string to the file.

Instead, use [csvwriter.writerows()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows):

```
with open("/home/oatey/" + du + ".csv", "wb") as wd:
     cw = csv.writer(wd, quotechar='', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
     cw.writerows(contents)
```

Comment: I get an Attribute error: 'module' object has no attribute 'writer'.  I try both csv.writer and csvwriter....

Comment: It worked after I deleted the files with csv in the title from directory.  That was causing the module to fail!